# OwlCarousel not displaying with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to implement [OwlCarousel](https://wordpress.org/plugins/owl-carousel/) in a WordPress theme where I use Bootstrap and imported the OwlCarousel assets.

Long story short: I tried OwlCarousel 2, it didn't work. I thought maybe there are conflicts with some things I use in this WordPress instance. So I tried OwlCarousel: Not working.

On every single.php page, for example http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/manufaktur/tischkorpus-m-goetti/ there should be an owl carousel just below the menu. My browser displays nothing. I'm not sure, where the issue is.

The goal is to display a full height carousel of images, defined in the article.

**EDIT:**
My used code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true
            // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
            // items : 1, 
            // itemsDesktop : false,
            // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
            // itemsTablet: false,
            // itemsMobile : false
    });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/owl/owl.carousel.css">
        <!-- Default Owl Theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/owl/owl.theme.css">
        <!-- Include Owl js plugin -->
        <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/owl/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item"><img src="http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/wp-content/themes/einfall7-2016/images/ref-einfall7-gr.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/wp-content/themes/einfall7-2016/images/ref-einfall7-gr.jpg" alt="GTA V"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/wp-content/themes/einfall7-2016/images/ref-einfall7-gr.jpg" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What code you have tried so far? Provide some code

Comment: It's give an owlCarousel is not a function error. So jquery conflict issue..

Comment: @Vidhi Added the code, thanks.

Comment: @hardiksolanki Maybe because wordpress automatically loads (an old) version of jQuery?

Comment: Can you try adding your owl.carousel.js in footer instead of header? It might solve issue

Comment: @Vidhi It does! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after you include the owlCarousel script you include jQuery 2.2.4.

As Wordpress includes jQuery there is no need for this (Except if you want to include the newer version yourself, but than you should [dequeue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) first).

Right now you have 2 versions of jQuery running on the site. I think that this is causing the problem with the owlCarousel. 
Remove the one you included and you should be allright.

It is best practice to include all the JS files you use by using the Wordpress enqueue function. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

This is a sample function to include the scripts:

```
/**
 * Enqueue script
 *
 * The callback is hooked to 'wp_enqueue_script' to ensure the script is only enqueued on the front-end.
 */
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owlCarousel' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed the jQuery code you mentioned and added some code to let wordpress implement a newer version of jQuery in the wp_header(); I also moved the owlCarousel-JS to the footer. Now it works like a charm.

This is the code i used in my functions.php:
`if( !is_admin()){
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"), false, '2.2.4');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}`